# Prevent users from creating multiple accounts

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, security

This question is just to prove how easy it is for the same person to create multiple accounts, since I have another primary account on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. Refer to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126741/multiple-accounts-being-used-to-dodge-a-question-ban).

Something needs to be done about restricting users from creating multiple accounts. Perhaps recognizing cookies, local computer, or something that identifies duplicate users. I created this account in Firefox, while my primary is always used in Chrome. However, I have signed into my main one from Firefox in the past. And a simple IP address ban is not sufficient, because many people have dynamic IP addresses at their ISP.

My point is, when people get banned, it just should not be this easy to create a new account. I'm only asking this question because this question should not even exist in the first place under this account. Many other questions are out there on the same subject. I'm only asking this on my second account to prove a point.

Comment: You know that having multiple accounts is allowed, right? It's only when you are using the secondary account to bypass the rules that there's a problem, but just having a secondary account isn't a problem by itself.

Comment: True, but after seeing some really fancy techniques from Facebook on how it recognizes and restricts duplicate accounts, I would like to also see it done here.

Comment: So you're asking for a rule change backed up by a software feature, but you're not giving any reasons why the current rule is problematic.

Comment: I don't expect this to go anywhere, I'm just merely pointing out that it's too easy, without any checking. This is a dummy account. Feel free to ignore this.

Comment: It's easy because it's permitted @DJJD.

Comment: When you get banned, the ban applies to all your accounts and you're not allowed to create a new account. It's not a reason to disallow secondary accounts from everybody.

Comment: How does StackExchange know which accounts are linked?

Comment: @DJJD, it's only know to SE employees. It's a fairly robust system but isn't 100% foolproof as if you have a lot of people within the same company using the same network connection it appears that that's a number of accounts coming from one IP. If someone is question-banned it's not that easy to create a new account as the ban "is above IP level". Any sort of duplicate accounts for vote fraud gets picked up fairly quickly and Dealt With.

Comment: IP addresses aren't the only way to recognize dupes... Reading cookies is one idea (however one can simply clear their cookies).