# What if a user uses multiple accounts with different names?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, multiple-accounts

I've read [Multiple accounts being used to dodge a question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126741), but the multiple account user has same name.

What I'm thinking is that I cannot know if a user has multiple accounts with different names and up-vote each other. I think that, if s(he) has 5 or more accounts, she will be able to close a question if s(he) wants.

I found a comment likes "I thought that tracking of IP addresses would stop someone from doing this." How about if the multiple account users use difference locations, and difference IP addresses?

Comment: Why would you need to know if another user has multiple accounts?

Comment: As I said , "if s(he) has 5 or more account , will be able to close or delete a question of other user if s(he) want , including your question :)

Comment: close,delete,approve/reject suggested edit activity requires more than one vote.

Comment: They'd need 5 accounts with more than 3K reputation each to close questions, and 3 accounts with more than 10K reputation each to delete questions. While not impossible, it's highly impropable.

Comment: How about if s(he) has 15 reputation each and up-vote each other ?

Comment: @Yannis: I'm not sure if we shouldn't welcome such a user, after all that's at least 2 accounts with 3k+ and 3 accounts with 10k+...which weighs in at 36k+ reputation...that's quite a contributor (cross-voting not included).

Answer (score 3):

If you are not a moderator, you cannot know if a user is using multiple accounts, in the same way you cannot know if two accounts using the same display name are really used from the same person.

Stack Exchange keeps under control some voting patterns, and moderators are alerted of suspicious voting patterns.

As per a person having 5 different accounts, and using them to close a question, that would require 5 accounts with a reputation of at least 3000. If that reputation is not gained from asking a question with an account, and giving an answer with another account (which is then accepted), that would require a big effort. If that person is really so good to get a total reputation of 15K on 5 accounts, I don't think he would use 5 accounts just to be able to close alone a question when the same question can be re-opened by 5 different users, considering that such behavior would be noticed.

Answer (score 2):

If you found such false voting activity, just flag it for moderator attention with "other" option and write your description in text box. Moderator has better view and tool to find such users.

You yourself can not perform such IP level activity, So better leave that matter with moderators.