# Sock-puppeting and multiple accounts

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, sock-puppets

There's a probability I've made a mistake as Stack Exchange moderator, and I just want to understand if it is indeed the case.

So I've noticed that a particular user keeps posting quite low-quality questions. Not only were they of low quality, they were sort of immediately recognizable - by seeing only the text I was able to guess who had written it.

I've actually almost never intervened because they were still on-topic.
Then I've realized that actually I'm looking at questions written by two different users that have very similar username.

I've checked and realized that this is the same person. Actually there's a third username created by that very person.

And here's the part where I possibly made a mistake coming.

I've recognized this behaviour as a sock-puppetting, chose the account with this maximum score and suspended it (for seven days) and deleted the other one.

I've explained the user that this suspension is due to sock-puppeting.
But! User had reached out to me and pointed out the fact that he is not using these accounts - yes, he acknowledged he owns all three of them - for anything like up-voting himself. Thus, he sees no reason for suspension.

So I actually need an expert advise how this can be checked. If I'm wrong at least I won't mess up things again.

Comment: This is something you should contact us about (use the "contact CM team" option from the mod menu on the user's profile). It's going to require more detail than can be given out in a public Meta post.

Comment: @animuson - sure, let me do it the right way

Comment: Using multiple accounts to circumvent question rate-limits is just as much abuse as using multiple accounts to upvote yourself. Beyond that... What animuson said.

Comment: @animuson ok, I believe I've reached CM team, thanks

Comment: Since this got closed midway through an answer - the fact that the user kept posting low quality questions is an issue too. Handling those would have been an appropriate and proportional first step, and much easier to fix than anything else. We do have a low quality question standard moderator message. The rest of it, yeah, I don't think you can get more authoritative than what our CMs said.

Comment: As a moderator I've come across two users creating new accounts to circumvent question bans and my "first warning" to them is "You appear to have created multiple accounts to evade a question ban on one of them.  This is very ill advised as you will read at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126746/215590  Please use these instructions to merge them ASAP: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts  Then fix questions of your sole account by reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th"

Comment: This seems... weird.  Does the OP not know about the Teacher's Lounge?  Or is that not a thing anymore?  Normally that's where you would go first if you had questions about moderation.  Even before you decide to actually take an action...