# Migration from one account to another

Tags: discussion, post-ban

There are too many negative markings on my questions on Stack Overflow. So I want to migrate my account to another new account. I want all my information to migrate except the questions.

Is it possible?

Comment: What purpose do you expect this to serve? Questions and answers are downvoted if they are not considered 'good' questions or answers; you would ultimately be better served to learn _how_ to improve your questions and answers, and then edit them to do so.

Comment: Oh, Okay.. Is there a way to migrate without question? @JeffZeitlin

Comment: You seem to only have two questions with negative score, and one is only on -1. If it's primarily the one question you want to get rid of, you can always [request that it be disassociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0). But there's a chance that question gets deleted in a few hours if you just do nothing (I voted to deleted it). Note: disassociating is not intended for many questions - even only your 4 questions might be too many.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not possible to start with a clean slate without deleting your account completely first.

All our activity on Stack Exchange is logged publicly for a reason, so that moderators and users with moderator powers can see the history of the user and based on that decide how to act, sometimes.

The public log of past questions, including closed and downvoted questions, is not there to shame the users, it's purely to help moderate the site better.

So please, accept it as such, and don't take it as something bad or personal.

And in case you consider starting new account(s) to dodge possible question ban, please read this first: [Multiple accounts being used to dodge a question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126741/multiple-accounts-being-used-to-dodge-a-question-ban) (TL;DR: don't create more accounts.)